# Removing bootloaders in efibootmgr

Tags: boot, uefi

Which of the boot managers are safe to delete?
I have a bunch of extra boot managers on my computer. I currently have arch linux installed on it. I learned from `efibootmgr` that among the bootloaders, #0003 is the boot manager being used currently.
Also `man efibootmgr` says that the ones marked with `*` are currently "active".
I am using `systemd-boot`.

###### output of `efibootmgr`

```bash
➜  ~ efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0008,0004,0001,0000,000B,0005,0007,0009,0006,0002
Boot0000  Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,971839ab-7aad-4e69-85c4-c433b449af61,0x800,0xfa000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)57494e444f5753000100000088000000780000004200430044004f0042004a004500430054003d007b00390064006500610038003600320063002d0035006300640064002d0034006500370030002d0061006300630031002d006600330032006200330034003400640034003700390035007d00000000720100000010000000040000007fff0400
Boot0001  Linux Boot Manager    HD(1,GPT,aeb7d56b-1fea-844b-9d20-1439cdefe89a,0x1000,0x1f4000)/File(\EFI\systemd\systemd-bootx64.efi)
Boot0002* Diskette Drive    BBS(Floppy,Diskette Drive,0x0)AMBO
Boot0003* Linux Boot Manager    HD(1,GPT,0fe53546-a446-e44d-968f-ad2fc24edc5a,0x1000,0x1f4000)/File(\EFI\systemd\systemd-bootx64.efi)
Boot0004  Linux Boot Manager    HD(1,GPT,28b68d55-8c0e-7746-9be8-3b540826ee3c,0x1000,0x1f4000)/File(\EFI\systemd\systemd-bootx64.efi)
Boot0005* USB Storage Device    BBS(USB,USB Storage Device,0x0)AMBO
Boot0006* Onboard NIC   BBS(Network,IBA GE Slot 00C8 v1550,0x0)AMBO
Boot0007* CD/DVD/CD-RW Drive    BBS(CDROM,P1: MATSHITA DVD+/-RW UJ8D1   ,0x0)AMBO
Boot0008  Linux Boot Manager    HD(1,GPT,ac4476c5-fdcc-a74e-9da3-0b8d72c51ae5,0x1000,0x1f4000)/File(\EFI\systemd\systemd-bootx64.efi)
Boot0009* Samsung SSD 870 EVO 500GB BBS(HD,P0: Samsung SSD 870 EVO 500GB,0x0)AMBO
Boot000B  UEFI: Hard Drive  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x2)/EDD10(0x2a010480)/HD(1,GPT,0fe53546-a446-e44d-968f-ad2fc24edc5a,0x1000,0x1f4000)AMBO
```

Comment: From what you’ve told us we cannot be sure. Is there a Windows installation on this machine? How many Linux installations are there? I wouldn’t touch any entry that references hardware; 0002, 0005, 0006, 0007. Check which GUID’s still exist on your system.  You should be able to find the one in entry 0003. If you only have Arch on this machine all the other Linux entries can probably go. Worst case you have to reinstall something although the Arch wiki tells you how to manually add an entry

Comment: You show 3 Linux Boot Manager entries with different GUID/partUUIDs. Do you have multiple installs? Or are the partUUIDs referring to ESP that have since been deleted. Compare `sudo efibootmgr -v` with `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid` if you have lsblk.

Comment: @PonJar I have one arch install, 0003, which is the only one I wish to keep. I had a windows install and various other linux installs previously, none of the boot managers corresponding to which I want.

Answer (score 0):

> Which of the boot managers are safe to delete?

The only ones that are 100% safe to delete, but futile todo so, are:

- The ones that your `UEFI-BIOS` re-creates automatically.

---

That sounds like a dumb answer but it's the only **100% correct** one without any other info...

To **prevent** certain entries from being **re-created automatically** by the `UEFI-BIOS` you need to either:

- Disable settings related to them in your BIOS. 
  (This is related to entries: Boot`0002`,`0006`,`0007`)
- Remove the bootloaders from the respective `ESP`'s of the drives they reside on. 
  (This is related to the other entries **except**: `Boot000B`)
- No idea about the entry: `Boot000B` 
  Maybe remove the `/EFI/BOOT/xxx` files from the respective `ESP`'s of the drives they reside on, because that is the default fallback bootloader used on the respective drives that creates an entry named "UEFI: Hard Drive"

**NOTE:** Be very careful with `Boot0000  Windows Boot Manager` as that might not be re-created at all by the UEFI-BIOS...